# Cannot access MS Reporting Services through SSMS

Tags: reporting-services

I can access report manager and I am the content manager in report manager. Using that same logon within SSMS I cannot access. This server was configured by someone else, but he told me he gave me all rights prior to him leaving. I have his logon and I get the same error. Cannot Connect to xxxx. The username or password is not valid.

When I changed the config files to allow form authentication I could access reporting services through SSMS but no rights to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need rights to?

You generally don't administer SSRS via SSMS unless you are working with security/roles.

If you need to reconfigure the Report Server then you would normally use the `Reporting Services Configuration Manager` which is a desktop app that is normally installed when SQL Server is installed.

If you need to manage the actual reports including subscriptions and schedules, then you would access these via the Report Manager (or Web Portal in SSRS2016 onwards). These by default are located at `http://myServerName/Reports`

Answer (score 0):

The default permissions on SSRS when it is installed grants BUILTIN\Administrators full Admin rights.

if you can get admin on the server, even temporarily, you will be able to get access to the SSRS settings in SSMS. Alternatively, get someone who would be a server admin to connect to SSRS & add you as a **System Administrator** from Report manager's **Site Settings**